# pandas resample when cumulative function returns data frame

Tags: pandas

I would like to use resampling function from pandas but applying my own custom function. The problem I'm facing is that the custom function returns a pandas Data Frame instead of a single array.

The following example illustrate my problem:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> def f(data):
...     return ((1+data).cumprod(axis=0)-1)
... 
>>> data = np.random.randn(1000,3)
>>> index = pd.date_range("20170101", periods = 1000, freq="B")
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data= data, index =index)
```

Now suppose I want to resample the business days to business end month frequency:

```
>>> resampler = df.resample("BM")
```

If I apply now the my function `f` I don't get the desired result. I would like to get the last row of my output from `f`.

```
>>> resampler.apply(f)
```

this is becaumes the `cumprod` in my function `f` returns a pandas data frame. I could write my `f` such that it returns just the last row. However, I would like to use this function in other places as well to return the whole Data Frame. This could be solved via introducing a flag like "last_row" in the function `f` which steers to return the complete or just the last row. But this solutions seem rather nasty.

Comment: I think this could be simplified if what you really want is to first apply the function, and then select the last business day of the month.  That actually wouldn't require resampling and it's the combo of resampling with a cumulative function that makes this tricky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just define your function `f` with a `last_row` parameter. You can default it to `False` so that it returns the entire dataframe. When `True` it returns the last row

```
def f(data, last_row=False):
    df = ((1+data).cumprod(axis=0)-1)
    if last_row:
        return df.iloc[-1]
    return df
```

Get the last row

```
df.resample('BM').apply(f, last_row=True)

                    0           1          2
2017-01-31   0.185662   -0.580058  -1.004879
2017-02-28  -1.004035   -0.999878  17.059846
2017-03-31  -0.995280   -1.000001  -1.000507
2017-04-28  -1.000656 -240.369487  -1.002645
2017-05-31  47.646827  -72.042190  -1.000016
....
```

Return all the rows as you already did.

```
df.resample('BM').apply(f)
```

Comment: thx that what I did for the moment, but it looks rather ugly IMHO. Is there not a more pythonic way to do it?

Comment: ugly? This is the pythonic way of doing it.

Comment: This is definitely a pythonic solution. Other solution with **lambda**: `resampler.apply(lambda x: f(x).iloc[-1])`. So you don't need to change the function `f()`

Comment: This is a good answer, but with respect, it's not the best possible answer in that it is somewhat inefficient by repeatedly calculating the cumprod (I say that based on my honest understanding of how the answer works, but I could certainly by wrong.  I'll post an alternate approach shortly and you can judge for yourself)

Answer (score 3):

I think you could refactor in the following way, which will be much faster for larger dataframes:

```
(1+df).resample('BM').prod() - 1


                   0         1         2
2017-01-31 -0.999436 -1.259078 -1.000215
2017-02-28 -1.221404  0.342863  9.841939
2017-03-31 -0.820196 -1.002598 -0.450662
2017-04-28 -1.000299  2.739184 -1.035557
2017-05-31 -0.999986 -0.920445 -2.103289
```

That gives the same answer as @TedPetrou although you can't tell because we used different random seeds, but you can easily test this yourself.  Though actually, I'm still sorting out why this gives the same answer via `prod()` rather than `cumprod()`.  Anyway, as you can see this is a mix of intuition and reverse engineering I'm using here and will update as I double check things...

For this relatively small dataframe with 1,000 rows, this way is only around twice as fast, but if you increase the rows you'll find this way scales much better (about 250x faster at 10,000 rows).

**Alternative approaches:**  These give different answers from the above (and from each other) but I wonder if they might be closer to what you are looking for?

```
(1+df).resample('BM').mean().expanding().apply( lambda x: x.prod() - 1)

(1+df).expanding().apply( lambda x: x.prod() - 1).resample('BM').mean()
```

Comment: you can use .prod() as a method directly (i think may not be implemented)