# What is difference between aggregation and resampling over historical data within pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, aggregate, downsampling

I'm experimenting with the characterization of data over time. Let's say I have the following time data:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.signal as signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Function to generate triangular wave
def generate_triangular_pulse(rise_duration, fall_duration, period, samples):
    control_points_x = np.array([0, rise_duration, rise_duration + fall_duration, period])
    control_points_y = np.array([0, 1, 0, 0])

    x = np.linspace(0, period, samples)
    return np.interp(x, control_points_x, control_points_y)

# Set common parameters
samples = 288
rise_duration = 1
fall_duration = 3
period = 5
num_triangles = 5

# Create a time array with 5-minute intervals
t_num = pd.date_range(start='2024-01-01', freq='5T', periods=samples)

# Plot 1: Positive Triangle Pulse
triangular_pulse = np.zeros(samples)
for i in range(num_triangles):
    start_index = i * (samples // num_triangles)
    end_index = (i + 1) * (samples // num_triangles)
    triangular_pulse[start_index:end_index] = generate_triangular_pulse(rise_duration, fall_duration, period, end_index - start_index)

# Convert data to a Pandas DataFrame
data = {'date': t_num, 'Positive Triangle Pulse': triangular_pulse }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df.head())

#               date  Positive Triangle Pulse
#0 2024-01-01 00:00:00                 0.000000
#1 2024-01-01 00:05:00                 0.089286
#2 2024-01-01 00:10:00                 0.178571
#3 2024-01-01 00:15:00                 0.267857
#4 2024-01-01 00:20:00                 0.357143
#288 rows × 2 columns
```

I want to downsample data from **min** to **hour** losing minimum information.

```py
resampled_df = (df.set_index('datetime')          # Conform data by setting a datetime column as dataframe index needed for resample
                  .resample('1H')                 # resample with frequency of 1 hour
                  .mean()                         # used mean() to aggregate
                  .interpolate()                  # filling NaNs and missing values [just in case]
                )
resampled_df.shape                                # (24, 1)
```

if we plot the output and compare them:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import pandas as pd

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(15, 4))

#  (nearly-)constant
axes[0].plot(   df['datetime'],  df['Positive Triangle Pulse'], "b.-" , label="constant" )
axes[0].set_title(f'Positive Triangle Pulse incl. {len(df)} observations')

# Resample of (nearly-)constant

axes[1].plot(   resampled_df.index,  resampled_df['Positive Triangle Pulse'], "b.-" , label="constant" )
axes[1].set_title(f'Positive Triangle Pulse (resampled frequency=1H) incl. {len(resampled_df)} observations')

#plt.tight_layout()
step_size = 12
selected_ticks = df['datetime'][::step_size]

for ax in axes:
    ax.set_xticks(selected_ticks)
    ax.set_xticklabels(selected_ticks, rotation=90)

plt.legend(loc="best")
plt.show()
```

[image: img]

I want to find out what is the best practice to achieve this that has minimum impact on data pattern behavior over time. If you check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46992158/10452700) which is very close to my objective.

Questions:

- what is the difference between aggregation and resampling if one translates by `resample()` and another one by `agg()` or `groupby()` methods?

  - which methods use (de-)selecting between records and which one represents/reflects other observations that digest?
- which of these methods has the least impact on the behavior of data over time?

---

- [Historical Data Resample Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57336794/10452700)
- [Resample/aggregate intervals in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66982446/10452700)
- [Pandas data frame: resample with linear interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25246842/10452700)
- [Resampling timeseries Data Frame for different customized seasons and finding aggregates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75280083/10452700)
- [aggregate groups results in pandas data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57830819/10452700)
- [using resample to aggregate data with different rules for different columns in a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53972633/10452700)
- [Need to aggregate data in pandas data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73411972/10452700)
- [pandas resample when cumulative function returns data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46214861/10452700)
- [Pandas resample data frame with fixed number of rows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44305794/10452700)

Comment: `resample` and `groupby.agg` are in fact quite similar (when performing downsampling), what will differ is that `resample` is specifically designed for time-aware groupers, thus it's often easier to use.

Comment: from your point of view in terms of characterization and pattern\behavior of data have minimum impact after using? how can keep data patterns possibly? (I do not mean de-scaling but a kind of data resolution ) I updated the post and applied `resample()` to show how it ruins the pattern of data and I also understand we lose the information and this might be the price we pay.

Comment: Your broken pattern has nothing to do with the function used to resample but rather the chosen frequency. You have to choose it wisely ;)

Comment: good point if it is the game changer. As you noticed I generated data with the granularity of *5 mins* so due to having big data I need to change my angle and downsample into *"1H"*. it means instead of checking 12 observations per hour with df shape of (288,2), I have one instance per hour then the df shape will be (24,2) but O loose data pattern and some info. So how one can trim\adjust frequency within`resample( frequency='?')`?